# How display a legend of an arrow created with quiver?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I put the legend of arrows drawn using `pyplot.quiver` or `pyplt.annotate` methods?

I'm currently using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import *


x, y  = [1, 2, 3], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
u1,v1 = randn(3), randn(3)
u2,v2 = randn(3), randn(3)
u3,v3 = randn(3), randn(3)
QV1 = plt.quiver(x, y, u1, v1, color='r')
QV2 = plt.quiver(x, y, u2, v2, color='b')
QV3 = plt.quiver(x, y, u3, v3, color='g')
```

I would like to put a simple legend which displays three different color arrows in such a simple way that,

```
plt.plot(x, y, color='r', label='red')
...
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [quiverkey](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiverkey) function to make a legend for arrows.

```
plt.quiverkey(QV1, 1.2, 0.515, 2, 'arrow 1', coordinates='data')
plt.quiverkey(QV2, 1.2, 0.520, 2, 'arrow 2', coordinates='data')
plt.quiverkey(QV3, 1.2, 0.525, 2, 'arrow 3', coordinates='data')
```

Comment: Good, but we have to know the x,y beforehand. How to set this with plt.legend() automatically?

Comment: I would like to know too. I found only writing the value of reference, like a ''qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E', coordinates='figure')''.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to plot an empty scatter plot and use the latex arrow as a marker:

```py
[...]

plt.quiver(x, y, u2, v2, color='b')
plt.scatter([], [], marker=r'$\longrightarrow$', c="black", s=120, label="(x,y) -> (u2,v2)")
```

It doesn't look good, but it is what it is :(